# Windows 7 Service Pack 1 Install Failing

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am having real trouble updating one of my machines to Win7 Service Pack 1.

Its an Asus P5K board with an X9650 Quad Core Extreme chip, which is a less common type of chip.

Was wondering if anyone has had issues with this kind of kit or if it may just be the motherboard is a little gone.

The error message I get back from Microsoft Update is `WindowsUpdate_80091007` and `WindowsUpdate_dt000` which are fairly generic errors.

Tried installing with the sp1 file based installer and got nowhere. The actual installer crashes with an `SP Installer has crashed`

Its a fresh install on a fully scrubbed drive (an Intel 120GB SSD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally got to the bottom of this.

Turns out it was the SATA controller. Curiously enough the P5K comes with two SATA controllers - a 4 port Intel one and then a JMicron single connector RAID one hidden away on the other side of the board.

I had been using the Intel SATA controller and when I swapped and used the JMicron sp1 ran perfectly.

There might be some kind of fault on the unit but I am using an Intel X25 SSD and there may equally be compatibility issues with the Intel SATA controller on this type of socket 775 board (which is quite old) and the SSD.

If you have an ASUS board with this type of twin controller setup then I would certainly advise activating the other controller in the bios and trying that one with Windows 7.

Thanks to Moab as I learned how to use msconfig from his post!

Answer (score 0):

Perform a clean boot, then try the file based installer again.

Click Start, type msconfig in the search box and press Enter

Configure Selective Startup options:

1. On the Startup Tab, click "Disable All" button
2. Select the Services Tab
3. Check "Hide all Microsoft Services" (very Important you do this step Before step 4)
4. Click Disable all
5. Click on OK
6. Click Restart.

After installing SP1 and restarting, restore your system to normal boot by doing the following:

1. Click Start type msconfig in the search box and press Enter
2. On the General tab, check "Normal Startup"
3. Click Ok
4. Click Yes, when asked to restart your computer